# Update Woocommerce product categories Programmatically

Tags: php, woocommerce

Update Woocommerce product categories Programmatically has been a challenge for me, I can Create, Edit, Add, product Categories via php no problem from external datasource. but for some reason the when the dproduct Categories change it does not deleted the old one and does not move the child categories over as it should.

```
Example: Main Cat A -> Sub Cat A-> Sub Child Cat A
         Main Cat B -> Sub Cat B-> Sub Child Cat B
```

is how it looks before the changes

Now the client merges the two main cat A & B so it should look like this but it does not

```
Example: Main Cat A & B -> Sub Cat A-> Sub Child Cat A
                        -> Sub Cat B-> Sub Child Cat B
```

and then it creates the other categories and makes the database larger than it needs to be.

This is my code:

```
function createOrUpdateCategory($name, $slug, $parent_id = 0) {
    $category = term_exists($slug, 'product_cat', $parent_id);

    if ($category !== 0 && $category !== null) {
        return $category['term_id'];
    }

    $category = wp_insert_term(
        $name,
        'product_cat',
        [
            'slug' => $slug,
            'parent' => $parent_id,
        ]
    );

    if (!is_wp_error($category)) {
        return $category['term_id'];
    } else {
        $error_message = $category->get_error_message();
        error_log("Error creating category: $error_message");
        return false;
    }
}

echo "<h1>IMPORT PRODUCTS TO WOOCOMMERCE - CREATE CATEGORIES</h1>";

// Get the list of categories before the update
$existing_categories_before_update = get_terms('product_cat', ['hide_empty' => false]);

$woo_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT MainCatName,MainCatSlug,MaincatUpdate,subCatName,subCatSlug,SubCatUpdate,subCatGroupName,subCatGroupSlug,GroupSubCatUpdate FROM `products`");

foreach ($woo_products as $woo_product) {
    $main_category_id = createOrUpdateCategory($woo_product->MainCatName, strtolower($woo_product->MainCatSlug));

    if ($main_category_id !== false) {
        $sub_category_id = createOrUpdateCategory(
            $woo_product->subCatName,
            strtolower($woo_product->subCatSlug),
            $main_category_id
        );

        if ($sub_category_id !== false) {
            createOrUpdateCategory(
                $woo_product->subCatGroupName,
                strtolower($woo_product->subCatGroupSlug),
                $sub_category_id
            );
        }
    }

    sleep(1); // Sleep for 1 second between batches
}

// Get the list of categories after the update
$existing_categories_after_update = get_terms('product_cat', ['hide_empty' => false]);

// Compare and find removed categories
$removed_categories = array_diff($existing_categories_before_update, $existing_categories_after_update);

echo "<p>Categories import process completed.</p>";

if (!empty($removed_categories)) {
    echo "<p>Removed Categories:</p>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($removed_categories as $removed_category) {
        echo "<li>{$removed_category->name}</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    echo "<p>No categories were removed.</p>";
}
```